# Dynamic Programming: Why can't we solve minimum no. of coins required to form a change with the concept of 0/1 knapsack?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization, array-algorithms

Concept of 0/1Knapsack-
Fill a knapsack of W weight using given weights.Aim is to maximize the profit.
Ans-Problem can be solved by either taking a particular weight or not taking a particular weight,depending upon which one is giving maximum profit.In this way optimal solution can be calculated.

Now,min coin change problem-Find minimum no. of coins to make a particular change.
Ans-According to what i thought, It can be solved by either taking a particular coin or not,depending upon which one is giving minimum no. of coins.
Only condition of maximum in 0/1 knapsack will be reversed.

But in actual solution goes like this-
[Answer given on geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-minimum-number-of-coins-that-make-a-change/)

now,variation of minimum coin change problem-where all the possible combinations of coins we have to find for a particular change,concept of knapsack is followed.I am not getting why??

[like here it is done-](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/)

Please help me in understanding why my thought process of knapsack is not working for minimum no. of coins to make a particular change.
Where am i going wrong?
Or am i wrong in the concept of 0/1 knapsack,If yes,Please explain both.

Comment: You're allowed to pick a coin more than once, unlike in 0/1 Knapsack.  Otherwise, I don't see what the problem is -- the DP in the first linked article is basically the same as the Knapsack DP, except with that change, the one you already mention (namely, that you want to minimise instead of maximise), and the fact that all weights are 1.

Answer (score 2):

This code gives the minimum coin change solution using 0/1 knapsack concept in dynamic programming. Here I initialized the 0th row of the 2-D matrix to be filled to Integer.MAX_VALUE-1 and updated the values for each denomination entry to make the sum asked in the problem accordingly.The last element of the matrix gives the solution i.e., the minimum number of coins to make upto the sum. If proper sum is not obtained through the denominations given, I return -1.

```
public static int coinsChange(int denomination[],int sum){
    Arrays.sort(denomination);
    int[][] coins = new int[denomination.length+1][sum+1];
    for(int sumIdx = 0; sumIdx<= sum;sumIdx++){
          coins[0][sumIdx] = Integer.MAX_VALUE-1;
    }
    for(int i =1;i<=denomination.length;i++){
        for(int j = 1;j<=sum;j++){
            if(j>=denomination[i-1]){
                coins[i][j]=Integer.min(coins[i-1][j],coins[i][j-denomination[i-1]]+1);
             }
            else{
                coins[i][j] = coins[i-1][j];
             }

        }
   }
   if (coins[denomination.length][sum] == Integer.MAX_VALUE-1){
        System.out.println("No solution found");
        return -1;
    }

   return coins[denomination.length][sum];
}
```